# Xcode Upload File (Image) to FTP site

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ftp

i want to upload a file, an image, to a website. I have read the SimpleFTPSample from Apple. It´s work with the TestPhotos but it´s too complicated. Can someone post a simple Code, where i can put my URL in it? I have used BlackRaccoon and ASIHTTPRequest but it doesn´t work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked easiest for me was to write a small php script and upload the file to that. The php isn't that sophisticated but it works

be sure to replace the urls with your site name

upload.php

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'Images/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "transfer successful at:   http://YOURWEBSITE.COM/{$uploaddir}/{$file}";
}

?>
```

obj-c

```
    NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;    name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", YOURIMAGE];




     NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newimageGlobal, 0.4);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://YOURWEBSITE.COM/upload.php";

    NSLog(@"upload url%@", urlString);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"--------------------------    -14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;     boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:imageString ]     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-    stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary]     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks. But i use a nas as a server. I can´t use PHP. Sry, do you have another idea?

Comment: I remember it wasnt working when trying to use just objective-c, which is why i had to use the php sript. You can still use the objective-c code, but replace the php with some other server script for uploading a file thats compatible with your system

Comment: Thanks. Apple´s code works, but i can´t understand the code :D

Comment: Does anyone know a different solution?

Comment: The apple code seems to be converting the image into a binary data object, and then submitting to the php as an http post with the image data as the body. Just replace the php with whatever REST service you can utilize on your system. You can use virtually any language to accomplish that